# Hammming code how to understand the matrix

Tags: hamming-code

I'm having trouble to understand how to make the matrix
Below is the sample one provided in an exercise along with the matrix 
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/marker-based-augmented-reality-iphone-or-ipad

It doesn't seem to match to the 5 x 5 marker bit assignment for each cell 
or even have enough rows... I'm not a mathematician so really scratching my head how this works.any help would be appreciated

```
int Marker::hammDistMarker(cv::Mat bits)
{
  int ids[4][5]=
  {
    {1,0,0,0,0},...yep make scense (white, black, b, b,)
    {1,0,1,1,1}, and then it gets weird!!
    {0,1,0,0,1},..
    {0,1,1,1,0}...please help I need my hair!!
   };
```

[image]

{1,0,0,0,0}, line 01

the Image below is the Marker Ive made could anyone help and would like to add
can anyone help me to understand the matrix so I can use it.

ALL matrix diagrams and explainations happily accepted ;P !

[image]